# Filename contains weird characters in FTP after uploading via PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, encoding, character-encoding

I uploaded my track via PHP to my server and now it shows up in WinSCP as:

`Dubmood - Mario Airlines (Razor1911 Crysisâ€‹-â€‹Keygen Edit).mp3`

When I run `ls -ls` via PuTTY it just shows normally as:

`Dubmood - Mario Airlines (Razor1911 Crysis​-​Keygen Edit).mp3`

And PHP calls it as:

`Dubmood - Mario Airlines (Razor1911 Crysis?-?Keygen Edit).mp3`

I have no idea what might be causing this issue, I tried using

```
$_FILES['audiofile']['name'] = mb_convert_encoding($_FILES['audiofile']['name'], "UTF-8");
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

What is causing this issue  and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's probably not the best way to fix it, but it works for me

```
$s = preg_replace("([^a-zA-Z0-9-_. \(\)])", "", $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that php is using UTF-8. If your filename has any characters >=char(128) then it will become a two (or more) byte sequence in php. So your name consists of â€ which is actually one character on your server. In order to upload it properly the filename has to be converted (in php). 
Say I have a string which I enter from my website:
My code   this then is made into My code 
which can be translated to My code using utf8_encode
Your filesystem (assuming it is windows) is running on iso-8859-1 win win-1252 or something like that (generally using double byte characters assuming you have a modern windows).
So you would need to convert the filename to something that complies to your server characterset. You can use iconv for that.
Of course you can also change it to iso-8859-1 or any other codepage.

A piece of code for your testing:

```
$s='Dit&is een+code#met%vreemdeÝ×tekens';
echo 'raw string:'.$s."\n";
echo 'filename_normal:'.filename_normal($s)."\n";
echo 'utf8-encode:'.utf8_encode($s)."\n";
echo 'iconv:'.iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1//IGNORE',$s)."\n";
echo 'mb_internal_encoding:'.mb_internal_encoding();
```

This gives the following output

```
raw string:Dit&is een+code#met%vreemde▌╫tekens
Dit&is een+code#met%vreemde▌╫tekens
filename_normal:Dit en is een + code_met vreemde  tekens
utf8-encode:Dit&is een+code#met%vreemde├¥├ùtekens
iconv:Dit&is een+code#met%vreemdetekens
mb_internal_encoding:ISO-8859-1
```

Yup I forgot filename_normal..

```
function filename_normal($s)
{
  echo $s . "\n";
  $t='';
  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){
    if (ord(substr($s,$i,1))<32){
      $t=$t.' ';
    }elseif (ord(substr($s,$i,1))>127){
      $t=$t.' ';
    }elseif (substr($s,$i,1)=='&'){
      $t=$t.' en ';
    }elseif (substr($s,$i,1)=='+'){
      $t=$t.' + ';
    }elseif (substr($s,$i,1)=='%'){
      $t=$t.' ';
    }elseif (substr($s,$i,1)=='#'){
      $t=$t.'_';
    }else
      $t=$t.substr($s,$i,1);

  }
  return $t;
}
```

Comment: the filename_normal() function is not a PHP internal function, the other functions don't change anything for me unfortunatly, the problem is (I think) that my string is already UTF-8, this is what my server outputs: http://imgur.com/abdzPRt